# Synonym for brute strength

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a one-word synonym for *brute strength*. Example usage would be the opposite of a tennis player that plays with finesse and grace; one that smashes the ball and gets the job done.

The word would be the antonym of *grace* and *finesse* in the sentences below:

*"His shots are played with such grace"*

*"His shots are played with such finesse"*

Comment: Are you asking about a verb or an adjective (or even a noun)? Is it something somebody *has* or *uses* or something that somebody *does*?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I've tried to clarify. Please don't be so quick to downvote/block a newbie! Thanks!

Comment: **brawn**.  Example: I am shopping in the DIY store.  Another customer asks me if I know what department to look in for Product X.  I say, "I think you can ask about that over in Building Supplies.  But be forewarned, most of the Building Supplies people seem to be chosen more for their brawn than their intellect."  Example for your situation: "His shots are played with more brawn than finesse.  Which doesn't always work out in his favor."

Comment: @aparente001 that's an answer 

Comment: @sumelic - Thanks for noticing and letting me know.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[brawn](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brawn)

> full strong muscles; muscular strength (Merriam Webster)

Examples:

> I am shopping in the DIY store. Another customer asks me if I know what department to look in for Product X. I say, "I think you can ask about that over in Building Supplies. But be forewarned, most of the Building Supplies people seem to be chosen more for their **brawn** than their smarts." Example for your situation: "His shots are played with more brawn than finesse. Which doesn't always work out in his favor."
>
> This is a tennis player known more for his **brawn** and stamina than his finesse.